# Magento 1.9: custom-html display issues when changing themes/designs

Tags: html, magento, reference, block, footer

I need to figure out why appending the content of the footer block only works with certain themes/designs. Using the rwd/default design my echoed Div is displayed, however if I change to, for example, the default/modern design my Div is not shown (even after clearing the cache of course). My layout xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="footer">
      <block type="core/template" name="test_footer" as="test_footer" template="myextention/test/footer.phtml"/>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

and in my footer.phtml I am simply echoing an Html Div.
The thing is I am under the impression that the footer block is existent for all themes, however **I am wondering if it has something to do with the type parameter** since it worked in a theme but not in a different one.
I have just gotten a bit familiar with Magento so I'd appreciate insights & hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to copy modern dir inside rwd dir?

Comment: What do you mean? To be clear, I am trying to build an extension that appends html content to the footer and it's not working in some designs.

Comment: If you copy modern design inside rwd directory, do you have the problem yet? Have you tried to disable cache?